# how to create shared folder so that my friend in other city can copy the content of that folder?

Tags: windows-xp, shared-folders

how to create shared folder so that my friend in other city can copy the content of that folder through internet?Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

you could use [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) on both ends. Will likely work more easily :)

Comment: yay. dropbox is the most straightforward for this, easiest to use.

Comment: and faster to boot. shared folder over VPN is terrible in my experience

Answer (score 1):

probable the easiest and most secure way, would be to use a vpn. Here are some solutions:

[Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) (Free and commercial versions)

[Easy VPN](http://easy-vpn.comodo.com/) (Free)

[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) (free)

They're all pretty easy to set-up.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a folder named as " shared folder" or something like that under the library or documents folder... if you put your files into this folder you can share them ... or just select a folder right click then select properties, there is a shared tab above you can share a file with this ... (but i didn't share a folder before so may be i am wrong) ...my OS is Win 7 but this operation should be same in winXP ;)